# How to use dependency in TestNG with two test cases from two different classes?

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng

How to use dependency in TestNG with two test cases from two different classes?
For Example, I have two classes:

```
package com.test.class

public class A{

  @Test
  public void testA(){

  }
}
```

---

```
package com.test.class

public class B{

  @Test
  public void testB(){

  }
}
```

The method **testB()** is depending on the method **testA()**, but they are in different class. I've tried to use `dependsOnMethods`,`dependsOnGroups` and XML dependencies. None of them worked.
Help me solve this!

Comment: There is no direct way. You can do one thing. Set a flag in `testA()` method. Verify that flag as True in `testB()`. If True then run ur code otherwise throws exception.

Answer (score 2):

In the @Test configure the group settings

```
package com.test.class

public class A {

  @Test (groups = "A")
  public void testA() {
    // Tests
  }
}
```

in the second code

```
package com.test.class

public class B {

  @Test (groups = "B", dependsOnGroups = "A")
  public void testB() {
    // Tests
  }
}
```

Then in the XML create a  tag and add all the groups that are created.

When running the second code will depends upon the first code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the method in a `group` and use `dependsOnGroups`

This may be help you [TestNG dependsOnMethods from different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692129/testng-dependsonmethods-from-different-class)